# Add index when same column value

Tags: awk

I have this two columns file :

```
ctg0F     chr_1
ctg1F     chr_2
ctg2F     chr_3
ctg3F     chr_4
ctg4F     chr_5
ctg5F     chr_6
ctg6F     chr_4
ctg7F     chr_7
ctg8F     chr_8
```

The first column has different values. I'd like to add an index only for the repeated values in the second column. Here `chr4` appears twice, and so :

```
ctg0F     chr_1
ctg1F     chr_2
ctg2F     chr_3
ctg3F     chr_4_1
ctg4F     chr_5
ctg5F     chr_6
ctg6F     chr_4_2
ctg7F     chr_7
ctg8F     chr_8
```

I do this :

```
awk '{ if (++count[$2]>1) print $1,$2"_"count[$2]; else print $1,$2"_"count[$2]}'
```

But this even adds index `"_1"` for the unique values.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { tot[$2]++; next }
    { print $0 (tot[$2]>1 ? "_" (++cnt[$2]) : "") }
' file file
ctg0F     chr_1
ctg1F     chr_2
ctg2F     chr_3
ctg3F     chr_4_1
ctg4F     chr_5
ctg5F     chr_6
ctg6F     chr_4_2
ctg7F     chr_7
ctg8F     chr_8
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples in single `awk` using its `END` block capabilities please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk '
{
  lineValue[FNR]=$0
  secField[$2]++ 
  lineSecondValue[FNR]=$2 
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){
     if(secField[lineSecondValue[i]]>1){
        print lineValue[i]"_"++currentSecVal[lineSecondValue[i]]
     }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

This 2 phase `awk` approach should work for you that computes and stores frequency of 2nd column in 1st phase and then adds a suffix when frequency is greater than one.

```bash
awk 'NR == FNR {++fq[$2]; next}
    fq[$2] > 1 {$0 = $0 "_" ++ind[$2]} 1' file file

ctg0F     chr_1
ctg1F     chr_2
ctg2F     chr_3
ctg3F     chr_4_1
ctg4F     chr_5
ctg5F     chr_6
ctg6F     chr_4_2
ctg7F     chr_7
ctg8F     chr_8
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl in-line script:

```
perl -lane '
$total{ $F[-1] }++;
last LINE if eof;
END {
      while ( <> ) {
                     chomp;
                     @fields = split;
                     $_ = join "_", $_, ++$cnt{ $fields[-1] } if $total{ $fields[-1] } > 1;
                     print;
                   }
}' input.txt input.txt
```

`$total{ $F[-1] }++;` : Count the **total** number of occurrences of the last column strings (`chr...`).
`last LINE if eof;` : Stop processing the file in first command line argument (`input.txt`) and skip to processing file in the second argument (which is also `input.txt`).
`while ( <> ) { ... }` : Read the current input file (`input.txt`) line by line, storing the current line in `$_` variable.
`chomp` : Strip the terminal newline from `$_`.
`$_ = join "_", $_, ++$cnt{ $fields[-1] } if $total{ $fields[-1] } > 1;` : If the total number of occurrences of the last field is greater than 1, then increment the current number of occurrences by 1, and prepend it to the current line.
`print;` : Print the resulting current line.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk '(_ = NF)*(FNR == NR) ? !++__[$_] :
>             __[$_]<_ || $!_=$!_ "_"++___[$_] ' file file
> ```

```
ctg0F     chr_1
ctg1F     chr_2
ctg2F     chr_3
ctg3F     chr_4_1
ctg4F     chr_5
ctg5F     chr_6
ctg6F     chr_4_2
ctg7F     chr_7
ctg8F     chr_8
```